# Pure css accordion menu overflow

Tags: html, css

Below is my problem:

I am trying to duplicate some accordion menu with pure css and html with my own understanding. But some odd things happen every time I click profile twice some overflow happens.

Can someone point me where the mistake is? And explain why that happened?

```css
.topped {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}

.menu {
  width: 300px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.menu .menu-toggle {
  background: #2980b9;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

.menu .menu-toggle:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu .menu-toggle:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid #2980b9;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 5px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.menu .sub-menu:target {
  max-height: 10em;
}

.menu .menu-toggle i {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.menu .sub-menu {
  background: #2c3e50;
  transition: max-height 0.3s;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menu .sub-menu ul {
  padding-left: 25px;
}

.menu .sub-menu ul li {
  padding: 10px 10px;
}

.menu .sub-menu ul li a {
  color: white;
}

.menu .sub-menu ul li a i {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.menu .sub-menu ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="topped">
   <div class="menu">
    <ul>
     <li>
      <a href="#profiles" class="menu-toggle"><i class="fas fa-user"></i>Profile</a>
      <div id="profiles" class="sub-menu">
       <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     </li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
     <li>
      <a href="#settings" class="menu-toggle"><i class="fas fa-cogs"></i>Settings</a>
      <div id="settings" class="sub-menu">
       <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-envelope-open"></i>Email</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-lock"></i>Password</a></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I removed `position: absolute` from the `.menu .menu-toggle:before` block, this seems to resolve your issue - however, I'm not clear on what the purpose of this block is, so you might want to just set this to `position: relative` so that you can troubleshoot.

```css
.topped {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}

.menu {
  width: 300px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.menu .menu-toggle {
  background: #2980b9;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}


.menu .menu-toggle:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu .menu-toggle:before {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid #2980b9;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 5px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.menu .sub-menu:target {
  max-height: 10em;
}

.menu .menu-toggle i {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.menu .sub-menu {
  background: #2c3e50;
  transition: max-height 0.3s;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menu .sub-menu ul {
  padding-left: 25px;
}

.menu .sub-menu ul li {
  padding: 10px 10px;
}

.menu .sub-menu ul li a {
  color: white;
}

.menu .sub-menu ul li a i {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.menu .sub-menu ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="topped">
   <div class="menu">
    <ul>
     <li>
      <a href="#profiles" class="menu-toggle"><i class="fas fa-user"></i>Profile</a>
      <div id="profiles" class="sub-menu">
       <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     </li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
     <li>
      <a href="#settings" class="menu-toggle"><i class="fas fa-cogs"></i>Settings</a>
      <div id="settings" class="sub-menu">
       <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-envelope-open"></i>Email</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-lock"></i>Password</a></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```